# XML DeSerialization returning Null values

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a POST method in a web API that has a `RequestAppointment` parameter. For example:

```
 // POST: api/RequestAppointment
            public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]RequestAppointment httpRequest)
            {
                var response = Appointment.CreateAppointment(httpRequest);
    
                return Request.CreateResponse<ResponseRequest>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, response); 
            }
```

`RequestAppoint` class has this structure:

```
public partial class RequestAppointment
    {
        public RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformation appointmentInformation { get; set; }      
    }
    public partial class RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformation
    {
        public string AppointmentCcEmail { get; set; }        
        public string ClaimType { get; set; }       
        public RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant Claimant { get; set; }
       
    }
    public partial class RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant
    {
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }        
    }
```

Two requests are possible to be made:
first one is:

```
<RequestAppointment>
  <appointmentInformation>
    <AppointmentCcEmail>x.x.com</AppointmentCcEmail>   
    <ClaimType>A</ClaimType>
    <Claimant>
      <DateOfBirth>1961-12-25</DateOfBirth>
    </Claimant>
  </appointmentInformation>
</RequestAppointment>
```

2nd Request is:

```
<RequestAppointment>
  <appointmentInformation>
    <AppointmentCcEmail>x.x.com</AppointmentCcEmail>   
    <ClaimType>A</ClaimType>   
  </appointmentInformation>
</RequestAppointment>
```

The difference between the two request XML is that #1 has Claimant tag while the #2 does not have.

The 2nd request does not have because the claimant is not supplied when users call the web service from data interface. While the first will always have when Claimant is supplied.

On my testing using Fiddler, my #1 request returns data. That is, it is able to deserialize into the object RequestAppointment, while #2 request returns null values.

What can I do to resolve this issue? The request will always come in those two formats and they will always use the same model structure.

What can I do to solve this issue? I tested the scenario in Fiddler.

Comment: Initialise `Claimant` with an initial value (like `NO NAME`) and overwrite that when the value is present.

Comment: The uses don't have control over initialising Claimant with value. I can only do that when testing from Fiddler

Comment: Add a constructor to RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant that initializes the DateTime property to "new DateTime()" so you always get a valid DataTime.  I think the error is occurring because the DateTime is null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  step 1. if you have `RequestAppointment` XSD file, the best solution is to generate class using xsd.exe [see haw to use it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx), if not you can create XSD yourself and do step 1, or finally you should make changes and point explicit attributes making your class XML serializable. There is a lot of article about it.

This class generated with xsd.exe , I create sample schema from you XML, made changes only in tag `<Claimant>` making it optional, and class looks like this. Pay attention how tool generates optional field `Claimant`

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class RequestAppointment {

    private RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformation appointmentInformationField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformation appointmentInformation {
        get {
            return this.appointmentInformationField;
        }
        set {
            this.appointmentInformationField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformation {

    private string appointmentCcEmailField;

    private string claimTypeField;

    private RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant claimantField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string AppointmentCcEmail {
        get {
            return this.appointmentCcEmailField;
        }
        set {
            this.appointmentCcEmailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ClaimType {
        get {
            return this.claimTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.claimTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant Claimant {
        get {
            return this.claimantField;
        }
        set {
            this.claimantField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant {

    private System.DateTime dateOfBirthField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth {
        get {
            return this.dateOfBirthField;
        }
        set {
            this.dateOfBirthField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

XSD example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="RequestAppointment">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="appointmentInformation">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="AppointmentCcEmail" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ClaimType" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Claimant" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="xs:date" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: VS 2015 comes with a similar tool that generates classes from XML on pasting. That is exactly what I used to generate the RequestAppointment.

Comment: Hi Seyran, Pls can you show me the syntax to generate with XSD? Thanks

Comment: Run VS2015 Developer command promt, and type this command `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>xsd.exe "full path to xsd file" /c /out:"full path to uotput der there the cs file will be created"` or this link will be more helpful I guess [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks for your assistance do far. Please how did you make the tag  <Claimant> optional in the xml? Thanks

Comment: In the simplest way, added tag minoccurs=0 , see edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still trying to adapt your suggestion. I have a question here: where in the generated code (*.cs code) is the Claimant option? Please can you point me to it? Thanks

Comment: At first generates a class `public partial class RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant ` it describes serialization behavior, then in `public partial class RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformation` class you have a private member ` private RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant claimantField;` and its public property `public RequestAppointmentAppointmentInformationClaimant Claimant {
        get {
            return this.claimantField;
        }
        set {
            this.claimantField = value;
        }
    }` which is your element in XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions. They are great! Seyran's answers really proved awesome. But in the case of my question, I solved it by nil="true" (nullable=true) to all the elements. And I used the xsd to generate the classes for my request xml.

Thanks